# Python os.cpu_count() on Mac returns wrong number of cores

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

Python's `os.cpu_count()` returns the wrong number of cores on my Mac.

macOS system report:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,3
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.9 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
```

Yet `os.cpu_count()` returns ***8***.

Is that a bug or I'm missing something?

This is Python 3.8.6; I also checked the Python v2 that comes with the system (using `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`) and the result is the same.

Comment: That machine has a Kaby Lake i7, with four cores but eight *threads*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaby_Lake#High_power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

os.cpu_count() returns the number of logical processors within the machines CPU, also known as threads. If it returns 8 then your machine has 8 threads, not cores.

Answer (score 5):

`os.cpu_count()` means threads not cores.